# why there is a `undefined` there when I want to console.log a string in node.js?

Tags: node.js

When I in the Terminal to execute the `node.js` code like bellow:

```
$ node
> console.log('Hey, Julie!');
Hey, Julie!
undefined
```

it should print the `Hey, Julie!` like above, but why there is a `undefined` there?

Comment: undefined is what console.log returns

Comment: @Dummy Thank you. I got it.